# sql: updating comma separator values

Tags: sql

I am looking for answer where i can directly update the comma separated values without splitting the comma values.

For Example:

```
old value   new value
123     111
234     222
345     333
456     444
```

Current

```
id  value
1   123,345
2   123
3   345,456,234
```

Expected

```
id  value
1   111,333
2   111
3   333,444,222
```

I have already used logic of splitting the comma values then updating the new values and then at last using coalesce to club all the new values with comma separator.
Since my count is too big this logic is taking lots of time for execution.

Can anyone please suggest me better solution for this?

Comment: Store the data correctly for a relational database (i.e. using a junction table) if you care about performance.

Comment: You will need to specify your database engine if you want a good answer, but odds are the answer is that there isn't a more efficient way to do this. SQL is designed to use table relationships to accomplish this sort of thing, not string manipulation.